# Proving an Irreducible Representation

Tags: representation-theory

Consider the representation $$\pi\colon \mathbb R \to GL(\mathbb R^2)$$ by $$\theta \mapsto \text{rotation by }\theta.$$

I want to show that it is irreducible.

I start with a non-zero invariant subspace $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$.

It must be of dimension 1... How do I move forward from there?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are proving by contradiction, as it seems you are, then we must show that the existence of a $1$-dimensional invariant subspace leads to a contradiction.  Any $1$-dimensional subspace $U$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is spanned by a unit vector $u$.  Now consider the action of any $r\in \mathbb{R}$ on $u$ that is not a multiple of $\pi$.  You should find that $r\cdot u\not\in U$, a contradiction as we have supposed that $U$ is invariant.

Comment: What do you mean by "that is not a multiple of $\pi$"?

Comment: @Moh: If we rotate a line through any multiple of $\pi$, the line will end up in its initial position.  If we want to show that any line is not invariant under rotations, we should show that there is some rotation that takes it to a different line.  Any rotation through an angle that is not a multiple of $\pi$ will do exactly that.

Comment: haha wow! I thought you meant the representaion $\pi$. I must be really sleepy!

Comment: @Moh: Ahh, I'm sorry!  I didn't see that you had introduced the notation $\pi$ for the representation in your question.  An unfortunate confusion in notation.  Glad we ironed it out, and I hope you soon get some rest.